# How to get last accessed date time of Azure database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to get last accessed date and time of each database in Azure Server. What i found so far is below query that gives us the last access:

```
'SELECT max(last_user_update) lastUpdate ,max(last_user_scan) as last_user_scan FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats'
```

However, the issue here is, I have to run this query against each database in order to determine the last access. I did not find a way to directly run a single query on the master database that can give me what I need.

I know that if the server is restarted, the last access date get cleared out and reset.

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: "last access" - that data isn't recorded by SQL Server unless you enable auditing - but even then it isn't particularly useful information. Consider things like caching and read-only secondaries, and so on... and if a database it in `READ_ONLY ON` mode then nothing will be recorded at all.

Comment: @Dai, that scenario is already considered. The above query gives me what i need but the only problem is, i have to open a new Query editor for each database and run this query against that database. I was looking for a better way of doing it

Comment: Azure SQL's "servers" don't actually exist though - they're just a logical grouping of databases that share some security `LOGIN` settings. That's why the `USE` statement doesn't work in SSMS. You **can** accomplish what you're after from a shell-script or Linqpad query, but not from a single SSMS query, sorry.

Comment: @Dai, I had a feeling of that. Thanks for the reply. I am going to try Shell-Script and see if I am able to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, generate output file using `SQLCMD` and append the results to file using DOS Shell. You have to connect to one after other database and get the result and append to the file.

If you look closely, first SQLCMD creates the output file(`>`) and subsequent SQLCMD appends to the output file(`>>`).

```
SQLCMD -S ServerName -D DatabaseName1 -Q "SELECT max(last_user_update) lastUpdate 
,max(last_user_scan) as last_user_scan, DB_NAME() AS Database_Name FROM
 sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats" > c:\dev\userAccessDetails.txt #creates outputfile

SQLCMD -S ServerName -D DatabaseName1 -Q "SELECT max(last_user_update) lastUpdate 
,max(last_user_scan) as last_user_scan, DB_NAME() AS Database_Name FROM 
sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats" >> c:\dev\userAccessDetails.txt ##appends to output file
```